# Continuous alerts in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have an instance in AWS that from time to time it's CPU cross the threshold of 90%.
I have created an alert for this, however I saw that I received one notification only and it was during the first 5 minutes while the CPU was at 100% for 2 hours.
How do I set the metric so I will keep getting notifications all the time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloudwatch does not send notifications continuously if the threshold is breached. Cloudwatch can send a Notification only when the state changes.

> Alarms invoke actions for sustained state changes only. CloudWatch alarms do not invoke actions simply because they are in a particular state, the state must have changed and been maintained for a specified number of periods.
>   Ref: [AWS Cloudwatch Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html)

One possible solution that I can think of is to create a Multiple Cloudwatch Alarms with Multiple thresholds.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer already says it is not triggered again, one thing you can do is changing the alarm conditions to a very large value and then the orginal value and the state change will occur again.